# Find first non-zero occurrence in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a time-series of Sales by Account ID. To calculate average growth, I need to extract the first month with non-zero sales for each ID. Since the account could have been established at different times, I need to dynamically identify when sales > 0 for the first time in the account.

The index to the row would be sufficient for me to pass to a function calculating growth. So I expect the following results by Account ID:

```
54 - [1]
87 - [4]
95 - [2]

I tried `apply(df$Sales,2,match,x>0)`  but this doesn't work.
```

Any pointers? Alternatively, is there an easier way to compute CAGR with this dataset?

Thanks in advance!

```
CalendarMonth   ID  Sales
8/1/2008    54  6692.60274
9/1/2008    54  6476.712329
10/1/2008   54  6692.60274
11/1/2008   54  6476.712329
12/1/2008   54  11098.60822
7/1/2008    87  0
8/1/2008    87  0
9/1/2008    87  0
10/1/2008   87  18617.94155
11/1/2008   87  18017.36279
12/1/2008   87  18617.94155
1/1/2009    87  18617.94155
2/1/2009    87  16816.20527
7/1/2008    95  0
8/1/2008    95  8015.956284
9/1/2008    95  0
10/1/2008   95  8015.956284
11/1/2008   95  6309.447514
12/1/2008   95  6519.762431
1/1/2009    95  6519.762431
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the index to that row amongst a subset of entries for an ID where the sales is non-zero? Because 4 for 87 is only if you subset this table, else it would be 9 (counting from top).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I haven't yet completely figured out how but with plyr and ggplot, I have visions of working on ID subsets, to efficiently calculate and show average growth stats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would this help:

```
tapply(df$Sales, df$ID, function(a)head(which(a>0),1))
```

where `df` is your data frame above?

If you want the entire row & not just the index, this might help:

```
lapply(unique(df$ID),function(a) head(subset(df,ID==a & Sales>0),1))
```

Comment: I edited and replaced your hardcoded indices (2, 3) with the column names (ID, Sales). Using indices is less robust. (Imagine the data comes from a file and someone decides to insert a column).

Comment: Now this is pretty close to @digEmAll's answer. The only diff is that by using `head`, you'll end up with a list in the case that an ID has no non-zero sale, while he will still get a vector but with `NA`.

Comment: Thanks a tonne @flodel. I think we answered nearly simultaneously... :-) Thanks a tonne for the edits. I should be more careful when copying from my trials at the R console.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies! The suggestion works but I'm not able to get to my goal. How do I extract the index from the returned vector so I can read Sales and CalendarMonth? Or am I asking this incorrectly? All I need is the first Sales amount and Calendar Month so I can run numeric ops on them. Sorry if these are novice questions because I am quite confused :(

Comment: Then your expected result is different from what was stated in the original question. Which is why I was wondering if you wanted the relative index as requested or the absolute index...

Comment: @A_K Apologies. I wanted first non-zero sales but I tried to part answer my question with the confusing 'index' piece. The objective though is unchanged and your answer is getting me there! Thanks.

Comment: No issues, @user1100825! We are all hacking away here. Edited my answer to provide you what you might be looking for.

Comment: I have my answer! Now on to figuring out plyr and ggplot to manipulate the subsets. This was my first question: this forum and all of you are just AWESOME! Shout-out @digEmAll. Alas, I can accept only one answer. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible solution:

```
res1 <- tapply(df$Sales,INDEX=df$ID,FUN=function(x) which(x > 0)[1])

> res1
54 87 95 
 1  4  2
```

Where `res` is a numeric vector with :

```
> names(res)
[1] "54" "87" "95"
```

If you want to get the indexes of the row in the original `data.frame` and not in the subsets, you can do:

```
res2 <- tapply(1:nrow(df),
              INDEX=df$ID,FUN=function(idxs) idxs[df[idxs,'Sales'] > 0][1])

> res2
54 87 95 
 1  9 15
```

Then you can simply use the indexes in `res2`, to subset the `data.frame`:

```
df2 <- df[res2,]

> df2 
CalendarMonth   ID      Sales
  8/1/2008      54     6692.603
 10/1/2008      87    18617.942
  8/1/2008      95     8015.956
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks promising! I'll give it a spin.

Answer (score 1):

Building up on [digEmAll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/316644/digemall) answer, a solution using [functional](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/funprog.html) programming (maybe a bit cleaner):

```
> res3 <- tapply(
  1:nrow(df)
  , df$ID
  , function(Idx) Idx[Position(function(x) df[x, "Sales"] > 0, Idx)]
)
> identical(res3, res2)
[1] TRUE
```